# Pull down gesture on tableview with loading indicator

Tags: ios, uitableview

When you pull down on a tableview, a white space appears above the tableview. The ask is to have the tableview stay in the pulled down state, and a spinner appear in this white space while the data is being re-fetched. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Initialize Refresh Control:

```
private let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
```

Assign the control to the table view:

```
tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
```

Configure pull gesture:

```
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshData(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

Implement refresh method:

```
@objc private func refreshData(_ sender: Any) {
    ...
}
```

When refreshing operation is finished, collapse the refresh animation:

```
self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
```